# Android OCR: Unsatisfied Link Error

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, tesseract

I am a student working on a OCR function for my school project. I am able to implement the functions and run the application successfully until now.

I have my application on Android Studio 1.5.1 and is able to run it on my **old device, Samsung Galaxy Note 3 API 21**. Recently, I **changed** my device to **Samsung Galaxy Note 5 API 22** and the application crashes whenever I try to run the OCR function.

Below is the logcat:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute
>   method of the activity
>          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4298)
>          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
>          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10557)
>          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21203)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) Caused
>   by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4293)
>          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
>          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10557)
>          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21203)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) Caused
>   by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512-2/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libpngt.so"
>          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
>          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
>          at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.(TessBaseAPI.java:43)
>          at com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.ShowImage.initTess(ShowImage.java:171)
>          at com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.ShowImage$OCR.onPreExecute(ShowImage.java:551)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
>          at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
>          at com.example.l33902.contactmanagment1512.ShowImage.startOCR(ShowImage.java:188)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4293)
>          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
>          at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10557)
>          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21203)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

I have implemented Crashlytics in this application and below is the cause of the crash as stated:

[image]

The error as stated is Unsatisfied Link Error, whereby it says that the application failed as it could not load the library "libpngt.so".

**The thing is, I have encountered this error before previously when working on my Galaxy Note 3 on Android Studio and managed to solve it by placing the "libpngt.so" inside "tess-two\libs\armeabi-v7a" directory. And it is still working on Galaxy Note 3**

As shown below:

[image]

Also I have searched many sites for the solutions. NDK build has also been built successfully.

Currently I am unsure of what I can do next, as I had solved this error before but the same issue appears for this instance while the previous solution isn't working.

Could it be caused by any other error that is not stated in thew logcat? Maybe the change of API? Just wondering, please help me out by giving any possible suggestions as I am still a beginner in Android Developing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Corresponding to the *.so file there might be a lib file. If then ,have you included those in build path of the project? Are you trying to port existing eclipse project or building new project? Can you try deleting folders under "app\build" and then Clean>Build

Comment: This used to be an ecilpse project, however I have ported over to Android Studio and it can be ran successfully. This problem only occur after I switched device to Samsung Note 5.

Comment: Which is the OCR SDK that you are using ? Check the OCR SDK version which you are using supports that device or not. Some may not work in higher versions.

Comment: @Harry Hi thanks for your response, the tesseract library file I used are downloaded from this link, https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two. It was able to run on API 21 android 5.0, my new device is 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Galaxy Note 5 is an ARMv8 phone. Try rebuilding the library with `arm64-v8a` on the `APP_ABI` line of your Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86 mips arm64-v8a x86_64 mips64
```

After doing so you should have six directories with *.so files under your `libs` directory.

Comment: Hi @rmtheis, thanks a lot for your response. I am now trying to run it on Note 5, it can already be run on the Note 3. I already have the line you stated "APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86 mips arm64-v8a x86_64 mips64" in my Application.mk file. So how do I implement it for the Note 5?

Comment: I just checked: Note 3 is armeabi-v7a, Note 5 is arm64-v8a

Comment: The following is the information currently in my Application.mk: APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86 mips # arm64-v8a x86_64 mips64
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8

Comment: OK. Remove the `#` from that line, and re-run the build. The `#` marks the beginning of a comment, so everything after that point is currently ignored.